# Facebook URL Schemes for share by ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, url-scheme

I want to share some text to ios app by URL scheme. I try to use "fb://post/%@" but i just open facebook app. Maybe have anyway?

Answer (score 0):

This is not officially supported, you should use the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) instead. Take a look at their docs for [sharing on iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios), that should answer all your questions.